# Numeric input writes content backwards

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have this app in ionic 3, and there's some numerical inputs like this:

```
<ion-item class="general-data">
   <ion-label floating>Input</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="number" formControlName="anyInput"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

We've been testing on a android tablet, and for this input, it's showed only the numeric keyboard (as intended). However, if I type "123", the input shows "321".

There's no function to force it backwards. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through this problem too, and noticed something...
When I type and the input is not visible on my interface, it reverses the value.
If the input is visible, it works like a charm.

When working with mobile forms, its common that the device keyboard covers a good percentage of the screen. When it covers, this error happens. (At least as I observed)
Didnt find any other discussion or topic about this. Dont know if its an android bug or something else.
Try to reorder or hide the rest of the content to ensure your input is visible on the screen.